# Apps not running at max refresh rate

Tags: framerate

I made the switch to Ubuntu 3 days ago and noticed that my screen refresh rate is at 144hz. But only my mouse move at 144hz and other apps like the terminal or Firefox only run at 60hz. I tried everything I could see on the web but no success. Any help? I’m running the 18.04 LTS on a laptop

Comment: How do you know that "the terminal or Firefox only run at 60hz"?

Comment: Well I compared to windows many times. The scrolling is definitely at 60hz in both Firefox and in the terminal. only the mouse is moving at 144hz :(